# In Gameplaykit, how can I add a delay GKGoal time in GKAgent2D behavior?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, behavior, gameplay-kit

I have a `GKEntity` that has a `GKAgent2D` component. Its behaviors are `GKGoal`, `toWander:` and `toStayOnPath:maxPredictionTime:`. The entity wanders continuously in the scene; however, I would like it to stop wandering for a while. For example, if the entity is a sheep that wanders about, I would like it to stop periodically to eat and, after a delay, start wandering again.

**UPDATE:**

In the **Entity**:

```
addComponent(MoveIdleComponent(maxSpeed: 60, maxAcceleration: 6, radius: Float(node.texture!.size().width * 0.3), entityManager: entityManager))
```

**MoveIdleComponent**

```
class MoveIdleComponent : GKAgent2D, GKAgentDelegate {

let entityManager: EntityManager

init(maxSpeed: Float, maxAcceleration: Float, radius: Float, entityManager: EntityManager) {
    self.entityManager = entityManager
    super.init()
    delegate = self
    self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
    self.maxAcceleration = maxAcceleration
    self.radius = radius
    print(self.mass)
    self.mass = 0.01
}


func agentWillUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {
    guard let spriteComponent = entity?.componentForClass(SpriteComponent.self) else {
        return
    }

    self.position = float2(spriteComponent.node.position)
}

func agentDidUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {
    guard let spriteComponent = entity?.componentForClass(SpriteComponent.self) else {
        return
    }

    spriteComponent.node.position = CGPoint(position)
}



override func updateWithDeltaTime(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {

    super.updateWithDeltaTime(seconds)

    behavior = WanderBehavoir(targetSpeed: maxSpeed)
}
}
```

**WanderBehavoir:**

```
class WanderBehavoir: GKBehavior {

  init(targetSpeed: Float) {
    super.init()

    if targetSpeed > 0 {
        setWeight(0.5, forGoal: GKGoal(toWander: targetSpeed))
    }
}
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code that configures the agent.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a `GKGoal(toEatFood:withFrequency:)` API, so you'll have to step back a bit toandthink about how to set the *agent's* goals to achieve *your* goals.

If you want the agent to stop wandering, or stop following a path, for some period of time, what you want is for those to no longer be its goals. (And furthermore, you want it to *stop*, not continue with whatever direction and speed when you took away its goals, so you'll want to introduce a `toReachTargetSpeed:` goal for a speed of zero.)

There are two general ways to do this:

- Have your behavior include wander, follow-path, and speed (of zero) goals, with weights set such that wander and follow-path outweigh speed. When you want to switch between wander+path behavior and stopping behavior, use `setWeight(_:forGoal:)` to make the speed goal outweigh the others.
- Have one behavior that includes wander and follow-path goals, and another with a speed (of zero) goal, and set the agent's `behavior` property when you want to switch between them.

Comment: thanks for reply, what do you think, is a good idea to use a GKState to switch between GKGoal? Or use a GKRule class?

Comment: I've just given you a light switch. You're asking about how to decide whether and when to flip your light switch, which is an entire universe of possibilities... perhaps best suited to a separate question, in which you outline what might factor into such a decision and what other decisions need making.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution with @rickster suggestion. I post it if can help someone.
I've added **pause** value.
if pause is true, the weight of speed change to 1, with `GKGoal(toReachTargetSpeed: 0)`

in **WanderBehavoir** class:

```
class WanderBehavoir: GKBehavior {

init(targetSpeed: Float, entityManager: EntityManager, pause: Bool) {

    super.init()

    var weightWander : Float = 1.0
    var weightSpeed  : Float = 0.0

    if pause {
        weightWander = 0
        weightSpeed = 1
    }

    //   |  |
    // --A--B--
    //   |  |

    if targetSpeed > 0 {
        let lato = Float(500.0)
        let pts = [vector_float2(-lato,0),vector_float2(+lato,0)]

        let path = GKPath(points: UnsafeMutablePointer(pts), count: pts.count, radius: 980, cyclical: true)

        let obstacleNode = entityManager.nodesWithUnitType(Tree)
        let obstacles = SKNode.obstaclesFromNodePhysicsBodies(obstacleNode)

            setWeight(0.5,          forGoal: GKGoal(toAvoidObstacles: obstacles, maxPredictionTime: 0.5))
            setWeight(0.2,          forGoal: GKGoal(toStayOnPath: path, maxPredictionTime: 0.5))
            setWeight(weightWander, forGoal: GKGoal(toWander: targetSpeed))
            setWeight(weightSpeed,  forGoal: GKGoal(toReachTargetSpeed: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

**In class** `class MoveIdleComponent : GKAgent2D, GKAgentDelegate` pause switch true and false after delta time randomly

```
private var lastUpdateInterval: NSTimeInterval = 0
var setPause = true
var randomTimeStop = NSTimeInterval(Int(5...8))
var randomTimeMove = NSTimeInterval(Int(10...20))

override func updateWithDeltaTime(seconds: NSTimeInterval) { 
    super.updateWithDeltaTime(seconds)        

    lastUpdateInterval += seconds

    if setPause {
        if lastUpdateInterval > randomTimeStop {
            setPause = !setPause
            lastUpdateInterval = 0
            randomTimeMove = NSTimeInterval(Int(10...20))
        }
    }
    else {
        if lastUpdateInterval > randomTimeMove {
            setPause = !setPause
            lastUpdateInterval = 0
            randomTimeStop = NSTimeInterval(Int(5...8))
        }

    }
    print("randomTimeMove \(randomTimeMove)")

    behavior = WanderBehavoir(targetSpeed: maxSpeed, entityManager: entityManager, pause: setPause)
}
```